jasper reports does not see xml datasource after upgrade to 6.20.6
Just after upgrading my jasper report library from 6.20.0 to 6.20.6 all pdf-s exported are empty blank pages.
I use Java, Spring Boot and jasper report.
I wrote simple junit which produces empty pdf-s in 6.20.6 and all 6.21 versions as well:
myXml =  //my inputstream with xml
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        myXml .transferTo(baos);
        byte[] buf = baos.toByteArray();
        InputStream firstClone = new ByteArrayInputStream(buf);
        InputStream secondClone = new ByteArrayInputStream(buf);
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        Document document = JRXmlUtils.parse(firstClone, false);
        params.put(JRXPathQueryExecuterFactory.PARAMETER_XML_DATA_DOCUMENT, document);

        JasperReportCompiledTemplateDTO dto = myTemplateCompilationService.getCompiledTemplateDTO();
        SimpleJasperReportsContext jasperReportsContext = createReportsContext(dto);
        JasperFillManager jasperFillManager = JasperFillManager.getInstance(jasperReportsContext);
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = jasperFillManager.fill(dto.getMainReport(), params); //also tried with third parameter: new JRXmlDataSource(jasperReportsContext, secondClone);

        JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
        exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(os));
        SimplePdfExporterConfiguration exportConfig = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();

        exportConfig.setTagged(true);
        exporter.setConfiguration(exportConfig);
        exporter.exportReport();

        exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
        exporter.setExporterOutput(
                new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput("target/employeeReport.pdf"));

        SimplePdfReportConfiguration reportConfig
                = new SimplePdfReportConfiguration();
        reportConfig.setSizePageToContent(true);
        reportConfig.setForceLineBreakPolicy(false);
   
        exporter.setConfiguration(reportConfig);

        exporter.exportReport();

Maven dependencies:
         <jasperreports.version>6.20.6</jasperreports.version>
        <xalan.version>2.7.3</xalan.version>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
                <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
                <version>${jasperreports.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
                <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
                <version>${jasperreports.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
                <artifactId>jasperreports-functions</artifactId>
                <version>${jasperreports.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>xalan</groupId>
                <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
                <version>${xalan.version}</version>
            </dependency>

And snippet from the jrxml file so that u know I am using xml as datasource and xpath for reading xml nodes. All values readed by xpath are null, like below autor name. Just like I would not provide any datasource..:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="my" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="1434527a-7db6-4d90-b5d5-3c385cggg2bf"> 
    <queryString language="xPath">
        <![CDATA[/root/details]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="car.owner" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.xpath.field.expression" value="string(./car/owner)"/>
    </field>

